# Is there a word that means "every four weeks"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a fourth word in this series: *weekly, biweekly, triweekly, ...*?

If not, and I had to coin a word, then would "quadweekly", "quadriweekly", or some other word be more etymologically appropriate? For example, is there a similar series from which I could borrow the prefix for "four"?

**UPDATE**: "Monthly" isn't appropriate because one month is a few days more than four weeks.

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to "monthly"?

Comment: I once worked in a company that handled computerised accounts/payroll for lots of others. We used to call the stuff based on "four-week accounting period" **fwaply** [reports, etc.], to distinguish them from reports/companies based on **calendar month**.

Comment: If you wanted to impress, you could always try 'quadrihebdomadal'.

Comment: I like the sound of "fwaply". I'm afraid other people will find it rather unobvious though ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "fwaply" is a great term, even though it sounds like something out of the mouths of [upper-class twits.](http://youtu.be/TSqkdcT25ss)

Comment: @MichaelLiu The words with bi- are not obvious/unambiguous either. Consider "bimonthly". It can mean both *"once every two months"* and *"twice a  month"*.

Comment: @Michael Liu: Presumably you've never worked in an accounting department in a country/business sector where four-weekly/calendar monthly accounting periods co-exist. To one extent or another I think almost *every* UK bus company has to deal with both at some level, and I'd expect almost all the people working in their accounts departments to either already be familiar with the term, or grasp it instantly the first time they come across it.

Comment: Maybe 'double lunatic cycle'; not sure.

Comment: @Kris: That's single lunatic, not double - at least if you are referring to the moon that orbits Earth and not some other moon.

Comment: @Drew see the pun ;)

Comment: @Barrie England: Not too impressive to mix Greek and Latin roots.

Answer (score 10):

Per Google, *bifortnightly* and *bi-fortnightly* together have been used about 5000 times on the web, frequently as objects of ridicule rather than as serious terms for "four-week-ly", occasionally as examples of misunderstanding of whether *bi* is a multiplier or a divider.

Although the lunar cycle is often thought of as 28 days, *lunarly* doesn't actually work to indicate 28 days, because the moon's sidereal period is only [27.3 days](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&q=lunar+orbital+period&oq=lunar+orbital+period&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2594l8486l0l8742l20l20l0l5l5l1l438l2256l6.7.1.0.1l15l0).

Regarding *quadweekly* and *quadriweekly*, I like *quatriweekly* or *quatri-weekly* better.
[Quadroon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=quadr&searchmode=none) and [quadrant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=quadrant&searchmode=none), for example, use *quadr-* as one-fourth, while [quatrain](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=quatr&searchmode=none) uses *quatr-* as four; but the roots of all of them are closely related to words meaning *four*.

Comment: *Quatriweekly* doesn't work, since *quatrain* came to English via French but we don't normally use it for our prefixes.

Answer (score 9):

Is there a compelling reason you cannot use "every four weeks"? The advantage of using the phrase is that there is less possibility of being misunderstood.

EDIT: You could also word it as "four-week" in the context you give in your comment below.

Comment: I have the phrases "weekly recurrence", "biweekly recurrence", "monthly recurrence", "annual recurrence", etc. For consistency, I'm looking for "*(adjective)* recurrence" for the four-week case.

Comment: If you coin a new word, it's possible you might confuse, annoy, amuse, or confound users. If you use something like "four-week recurrence" then you will improve usability, while sacrificing only a little consistency.

Comment: @MichaelLiu  As further evidence of its naturalness, I submit the fact that you yourself used "four-week" as an adjective in your comment :)

Comment: Shakespeare, Roald Dahl and Dr. Suess called me and told me it's ok for folks to invent a new word now and then.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that's actually better than "every four weeks" unless this distinction comes up so much that your office creates their own jargon for it. (See above for the lovely *fwaply*.)

The problem with trying to sound clever by coining something from roots and prefixes is that the people who grok *quadriweekly* or *quadweekly* quickly and intuitively will also understand it's kinda off, since *week* is Germanic.

The best you've got is *four-weekly* unless you're showing off with *tetrahebdomadally*, *quadriseptimanally*, or *duodetrigintally*.